# Creating Oracle Connection causes error in COM class retrieval

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I am writing an application in VB.NET that requires that I query an Oracle database using the Oracle Data Access Client. I then use something called the SCAPI interface to access the metadata of an application we use for data modeling.

I've simplified the problem down to just two functions that are executed by clicking buttons on a form.

This function is executed when I click a button on the form. It creates an oracle connection but doesn't actually execute any queries (because I've commented the rest out and still get the error):

```
Private Sub btnDisplayDirectories_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisplayDirectories.Click
    Dim ModelMart As String = "Data Source=...;User Id=...;Password=...;"
    Dim OraConn As New OracleConnection(ModelMart)
    OraConn.Open()
    OraConn.Close()
    OraConn.Dispose()
End Function
```

This function just creates the application object using the SCAPI interface:

```
Private Sub btnOpenModel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)         Handles btnOpenModel.Click
    Dim oAPI As New SCAPI.Application
End Sub
```

There is no issue if I fire up the application, and click on btnOpenModel first, then click on btnDisplayDirectories. If I click on btnDisplayDirectories, then I click on btnOpenModel, I get an error on the first line of btnOpenModel that says:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {2B2219EB-EDE7-49EE-BB89-5A0B4A398A63} failed due to the following error: 80004005.
```

I've actually experimented and I don't even have to open the Oracle connection to get this error, just defining the Oracle Connection causes the error.

Comment: During my debugging process, I decided to try a workaround which involved creating an Odbc connection to the Oracle database. I then used the System.Data.Odbc .NET Framework Data Provider to run my query. This still causes the error, upon further inspection, I noticed that System.Data.Odbc loads the same .DLLs as Oracle.DataAccess.Client. I thought maybe this was due to some resources being required by the SCAPI interface not being released but when I run both query functions (oracle and odbc) one after the other, they work fine. So I'm still stuck.

Comment: I've also tried a few things that I found on Google. They include compiling the project for x86 and changing the group policy for 'Do not forcefully unload the user registry at user logoff' (was a shot in the dark).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating the SCAPI.Application object as a global variable. This causes SCAPI to get its hands on whatever resources it requires before the database objects do. I wasn't able to figure out exactly why SCAPI and Oracle/ODBC assemblies don't play nice with each other.